# can anyone resolve this multiple alerts in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

it is generating multiple buy and sell signals, need only one buy and sell alert

```
buy=thisCCI >=0
sell=thisCCI<=0
barcolor(thisCCI >= 0 ?lime:red)
plotshape(buy, title='up arrow', style=shape.triangleup, location =location.belowbar, color=lime,size=size.tiny)
plotshape(sell, title ='down arrow', style=shape.triangledown,location = location.abovebar,color = red,size=size.tiny)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generating multiple signal because your conditions are `true` for multiple bars.

You need to look for a change.

```
is_new_buy = not buy[1] and buy
is_new_sell = not sell[1] and sell

plotshape(is_new_buy, title='up arrow', style=shape.triangleup, location =location.belowbar, color=lime,size=size.tiny)
plotshape(is_new_sell, title ='down arrow', style=shape.triangledown,location = location.abovebar,color = red,size=size.tiny)
```